# Count return duplicate value sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was using a fuction `count` and it returns duplicate value.

This is my code:

```
select 
count(concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string))) as transactional_id,
concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string)) as fullvisitor_visitId

from `table`

group by fullvisitor_visitId

order by transactional_id desc
```

and it returns:

```
Row transactional_id    fullvisitor_visitId 
1   500                 69084186004901620541643035790
2   500                 43445200361392401461643247660
3   500                 42244917333337992241643352791
4   457                 22347562727001104331641920097
```

As you can see, it count 500 3 times. In addition, I actually have like 100k rows, but somehow it only counts up to 500. Anybody knows how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: your each row is distinct for transactional_id=500

Comment: @Zaynul Could you elaborate further? Yes, each row is distinct and the transactional_id shouldn't return the same value

Comment: so for transactional_id=500 which row you want  into the result data set

Comment: You have to update your question with more details. You main question was already answered. I think you should either accept the answer and open a new case with more details or update your main question and add input data and desire output data. As well as additional logic behind what you want to achieve with it. ( share dummy data if possible ). Please visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Group by fullvisitor_visitId
because values of fullvisitor_visitId are different so SQL put them into 3 groups

Comment: I have to group by because the code wouldn't run. What can I do to make it count normally?

Comment: I get it now , apparently, the 500 is the count of fullvisitor_visitId, which has the same value 500 times.

Comment: I don't know what result do you want.

Comment: show me what result is your point

Comment: I have 2 tables, and I use function `count(distinct(key))` to count the distinct value. However, when I create another table, it shows that the value has increased by 400. Now, I am trying to figure out which value cause it to duplicate. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: if duplicated values are in a same table
`select Count(col1),clo1 from table group by col1 having count(col1)>1 `

Comment: Unfortunately, it occurs on 2 tables.

Comment: it's really hard to find your problem without structure if you can send min script of your tables